# Is boost::typeindex::ctti_type_index a standard compliant way for compile-time type ids for some cases?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, typeid

I'm currently evaluating possibilities in changing several classes/structs of a project in order to have them usable within a constexpr-context at compile time. A current game stopper are the cases where `typeid()` and `std::type_index` (both seem to be purely rtti-based?) are used that cannot be used within a constexpr-context.

So I came across with boost's [boost::typeindex::ctti_type_index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/type_index/ctti_type_index.hpp)

They say:

> boost::typeindex::ctti_type_index class can be used as a drop-in
> replacement for std::type_index.

So far so good. The only exceptional case I was able to find so far, that one should be aware of when using it, is

> With RTTI off different classes with same names in anonymous namespace
> may collapse. See 'RTTI emulation limitations'.

which is currently relevant at least for gcc, clang and Intel compilers and not really surprising. I could live with that restriction so far. So my first question here is: Besides the issue with anonymous namespaces, does boost fully refer to standard compliant mechanisms in achieving that constexpr typeid generation? It's quite hard to analyze that from scratch due to too many compiler dependent switches. Did anybody gain experience with that already for several scenarios and might mention some further drawbacks I do not see here a priori?

And my second question, quite directly related with the first one, is about the details: How does that implementation work at "core level", especially for the comparison context?

For the comparison, they use

```
BOOST_CXX14_CONSTEXPR inline bool ctti_type_index::equal(const ctti_type_index& rhs) const BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
    const char* const left = raw_name();
    const char* const right = rhs.raw_name();
    return /*left == right ||*/ !boost::typeindex::detail::constexpr_strcmp(left, right);
}
```

Why did they out comment the raw "string" inner comparison? The raw name member (inline referred from `raw_name()`) itself is simply defined as

```
const char* data_;
```

So my guess is, that at least within a fully constexpr context if initialized with a `constexpr char*`, the simple comparison should be standard compliant (ensured unique pointer adresses for inline-objects, i.e. for constexpr respectively?)? Is that already fully guaranteed by the standard (here I focus on C++17, relevant changes for C++20?) and not used here yet due to common compiler limitations only? (BTW: I'm generally struggling with non-trivial non self-explanatory out commented sections in code...) With their `constexpr_strcmp`, they apply a trivial but expensive character-wise comparison what would have been my custom way too. Trivial to see here, that the simple pointer comparison would be the preferred one further on.

**Update due to rereading my own question**: So at least for the comparison case, I currently understand the mechanisms for the enabled code but are interested in the out-commented approach.

Comment: I am curious if you ever figured this out yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately not in terms of this non-used char pointer comparison. Even for the latest boost version, it's still outcommented. And this part of the library doesn't seem to be widely used so far. And our team decided not to focus on that currently. I'm going to update the OP as soon as I figure out something new. Maybe I'm going to ask the author himself.

Comment: Update: I mailed Antony Polukhin, the author of these boost components, but no answers unfortunately.